# Python3 best way to read unknown multi line input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input, eof

What is the best way in Python 3 to read in multi-line user input when the amount of input is unknown? The multi-line input will be separated by Enter

when I try using

```
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
          print(line)
    else:
          break
```

I receive an EOFError

Then if I change it to a try-catch block

```
while True:
    line = input()
    try:
          print(line)
    except EOFError:
          break
```

I still get the EOFError.

Comment: That's logical, since the error does not occur at printing, but at `input()`. So that should be in the `try`.

Comment: Are you piping data in from stdin? I've never seen an EOFError from calling `input` but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: @AdamSmith: yes, if you use `Ctrl+D` in most terminals, this is also seen as termining the stdin.

Comment: The dupe is one of the most concise, smartest answers out there.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the dupe does not answer the question. As specified in my title I ask specifically for Python 3. The dupe is for Python 2

Comment: @Mazzone did you not see the part of the answer that addresses python3?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ input versus raw_input is used

Comment: @Mazzone That is for python3. What is your issue?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ please remove the duplicate tag, this is persistent problem in StackOverflow as explained here: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Python-unsuitable-as-a-mobile-application-development-language

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **`EOFError` occurs when you call `input()`**, not when you test it, nor when you print it. So that means you should **put `input()` in a `try` clause**:

```
try:
    line = input()
    print(line)
except EOFError:
    break
```

That being said, if `input` reads from the standard input channel, you can use it as an iterable:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end='')
```

Since every `line` now ends with the new line character `'\n'`, we can use `end=''` in the `print` function, to prevent print a new line twice (once from the string, once from the `print` function).

I think the last version is more elegant, since it almost syntactically says that you iterate over the `stdin` and processes the lines individually.

Comment: But the last line might cause problems, won't it? Mimicking `input()` exactly might be subtle

Comment: @Elazar: based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) of input, it reads from the stdin, strips the new line, and returns that. And raises an `EOFError` in case it has an EOF char. This is afaik the same what the iterator protocol over a `stdin` does (except that it terminates the loop in case of an EOF, and that it does not strip the new line).

Answer (score 0):

Break the loop if input is blank,

```
a = []
while True:
   user_input = input()
   if user_input == '':
     break
   else:
       a.append(int(user_input))
       
print(sum(a))
```

produces,

```
3

3

[Program finished]
```

If you know the range,

```
x, *z= [int(input()) for _ in range(3)]
print(x + sum(z))
```

produces,

```
3
4
5
12

[Program finished]
```